# webBrowser popup window loses session

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am using WebBrowser control of .NET to login into a website. When i click on a button that popups a new window the popup window asks me to login again. However i am not asked to login again if i open the webpage in internet explorer. Is there any way to  make the WebBrowser control store session so that i do not have to login again on the popup window.

Comment: I know this is an old post. but I had to search for a while to find this answer. so I am posting this link here to make it easier for others. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/setting-popup-window-to-be-a-child-of-mdi-control-when-using-webbrowser-control?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

To maintain the session state you *can* use the `NewWindow2` event to open the new page in another form in the application; the event is triggered by the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: What is this NewWindow2 event, I can't find it in my control. I am using .NET 2.0 in WinForms.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that before clicking the button you already made Login.

In both cases, I think the solution which I am going to give will work for you.

For this purpose, I think you place login fields in panel and on page_load check either session empty or not if not then visible it false if yes then visible it true.