# How to stop a Webbrowser Control that Opens Links in IE?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control that opens a third party web app and then. When user clicks on the links it opens into IE. How to stop that and open them in same control or in a different web browser control?

Comment: try to change target to "_self" or make firefox your default browser

Comment: I want to open that link in that webbrowser control that wpf provides and i cannot control the links as its a third party app.

Comment: I understand, but if the app says open this link in new window than you can't do anything, maybe there is something in config, read documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting popup window to be a child of MDI Control when using WebBrowser Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/setting-popup-window-to-be-a-child-of-mdi-control-when-using-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Yes i was able to control upto one popup but the other popup forces me to IE it doesnt even call back any code so that i can handle that request.

Comment: Use the DOM interfaces to modify the links to target "_self".