# Web Browser New Window Problem

Tags: c#, .net, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting popup window to be a child of MDI Control when using WebBrowser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/setting-popup-window-to-be-a-child-of-mdi-control-when-using-webbrowser-control)

When I click a link `< a onclick="OpenNewWindow(); />` in my WebBrowser control, I'd like to have the link open in a new WebBrowser .

I'm having two issues with this, however.

1. How do I get the new URL
2. How will the new browser window get the current Cookie?

   ```
   webBrowser1.NewWindow += (o, e) =>
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
       Form2 f = new Form2();
       f.URL = ""; // How to get the new url 
       f.Cookie = ""; // How to copy the cookie to the new webbrowser?
       f.ShowDialog();
   };
   ```

Comment: Agree it's a dup.  (The MDI part of the dup is not material to the answer provided.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from WebBrowser and CancelEventArgs and customize the behavior completely.  See this bug report and workaround from Microsoft: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115195/webbrowser-newwindow-event-does-not-give-the-url-of-the-new-window-in-eventargs

Comment: Thanks for your advice... But if when I  logging failed ,  This will always be exuted...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean.

Comment: In my login method ....[webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("form1:btn_login")[0].InvokeMember("click");]   So , If the the check is false , it will always excute the navigate ?

Comment: My bad - I wasn't paying enough attention to what you wanted.  I've deleted the second part of my answer, and also, I think your code there is just fine.