# C# Can I Automate Drop Down Box in webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, web, automation, drop-down-menu

Hi this is my First time on here, learning C# at the moment and have hit a roadblock

I have a program that clicks through a webpage using the Webbrowser control, and I need it to pick options from a drop down box.

I have the HTML for the page, and so far I have been using element.InvokeMember for clicking buttons, and element.InnerText for inputing data.

Is there any way to manipulate a websites drop down box and pick values?

I have The ID for the Drop down box element and values for its options.

Comment: Just a suggestion. If you are looking to automate websites, may I suggest to use a testing framework such as Selenium. But if this is only for learning purposes, ignore my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

set the value of the option into the selected field

ie selected="ID"

Answer (score 0):

I aswered to same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884215/popup-problem-in-mshtml/17831770#17831770) , and quote myself.
One can get handle to popup by WindowFromPoint function. Then you may use IAccessible interface to acsess elements of popup. Something like this:

```
const uint OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0;
Guid  IID_IAcce = new Guid("{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}");

IntPtr inpt = WindowFromPoint( p);

object ptr1 = null;
int l;

l = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(inpt, OBJID_NATIVEOM,    IID_IAcce.ToByteArray(), ref ptr1);
var acc = ptr1 as IAccessible;
```