# .NET Win Form App - Is it possible to catch a web address from a pop-up?

Tags: .net, popup, try-catch

I have a Windows Form Application that has a tabControl with a webbrowser on a tab an on the other some textboxes. I need to access a website from the webbrowser. The problem is on that website i have click on a link that opens a pop-up. I was wondering if there is any way to avoid the popup and load the page in the webbrowser directly. If there's a way to catch the popup address, close the popup and load the page in the application's browser. The real problem would be catching the popup address if that's possible. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a suggestion: You may want to add the Winforms tag to this question to get a bigger audience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting popup window to be a child of MDI Control when using WebBrowser Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/setting-popup-window-to-be-a-child-of-mdi-control-when-using-webbrowser-control)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to modify how the website works.  You could also simply navigate to the page within the pop-up manually.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible because the popup will occur within the web browser instance. It is pretty much outside of your control at that point.