# Is there a way to tell the Wiinforms WebBrowser control to use the current browser to open a hyperlink in?

Tags: winforms, browser

I have a winforms application with a web browser control.  I am wondering if there is a way to tell the browser control to open a URL in the current active browser, regardless of whether or not it is the default browser.  My gut instinct is that this simply isn't feasible, as this control is utilizing the operating system's default browser as defined by the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting popup window to be a child of MDI Control when using WebBrowser Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/setting-popup-window-to-be-a-child-of-mdi-control-when-using-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Redirecting it back to the same WebBrowser didn't work when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

or just try this one:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    Dim myElement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim target As String = myElement.GetAttribute("href")
    Dim newInstance As New Form1
    newInstance.Show()
    newInstance.WebBrowser1.Navigate(target)
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I use that if I handed in a hwnd for the active browser, not the web browser control ion the form?

Comment: Dim target As String = myElement.GetAttribute("href")
---------
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target) --------- e.Cancel = True