# Is it possible to force a WebBrowser to, instead of opening in a new window, replace the currently opened window?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

So I have a link I'm trying to click on a WebBrowser control. The problem is it pops up in a new tab, making IE open. I can't manage the web pages after it opens in IE, so I need to force it to somehow stay within my program. It doesn't matter if another WebBrowser control needs to open or anything, just so long as it says in my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting popup window to be a child of MDI Control when using WebBrowser Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/setting-popup-window-to-be-a-child-of-mdi-control-when-using-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few ways you can do this, one way is to loop through the DOM (Document Object Model) and find the link which opens in a new window, and change its "target=" attribute value to "target=_top" this way it will open in current top-level page of your current WB Control container.

Otherwise, there is a NewWindow2 event which you can intercept, write the following code inside that event (where WB1 is you WebBrowser Controls name):

```
Processed = True
WB1.Navigate2 URL
```

This will tell your WB Control that the request has been processed (tricking it into believing that it has been processed), and if you just did this, nothing would happen, so after the first line you write the second line which tells it to open the URL that it just tried to open in the new window, in the current window (WB1), so really you are just reissuing the request but for the same container/WB Control where the link was clicked.

I've written the code in VB, however I'm sure it's not a problem to understand and transfer to c#.

Let me know how you get along and if there is anything else i can do to help.