# how to change the behavior of WebBrowser object in c#.Net framework

Tags: c#, .net

Opening a ftp url through webBrowser object makes the output to appear like it has been opened in windows explorer. The problem is when I double-click a directory to enter, it just opens up a new windows explorer window with the directory contents. Is it possible to change this behavior?

```
//navigating to the required ftp address
webBrowser1.Navigate(
    "ftp://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + ip  +"/", 
    null, 
    null, 
    "Authentication : Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + ":" + pass)) + "\r\n");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display a popup from a WebBrowser in another window I created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/how-do-i-display-a-popup-from-a-webbrowser-in-another-window-i-created)

Comment: the problem is that a new windows explorer windows is opening on navigating the ftp url and not a WebBrowser.