# How to open dynamic WebBrowser link address in new window form?

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

I have found the error at href so please help me

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    Dim thiselement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim targeturl As String = thiselement.GetAttribute("href") 
    e.Cancel = True
    Dim window As New Form1
    window.Show()
    window.WebBrowser1.Navigate(targeturl)
End Sub
```

at "href" i have found error like Object reference not set to an instant of object.
my code is in vb.net 2010.

Comment: What's the error? Do you have any stacktrace to analyze? Also, this is vb.net, **it is not Java nor PHP nor C#**

Comment: Why on earth would someone with complete control of his mind tag this as `Java`?

Comment: @RohitJain because people *can* =\

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6470842/1768303

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement` is returning `Nothing` because there is no active element. Therefore when you attempt to use `targeturl`, you get this error: `Object reference not set to an instant of object`

Comment: @PinalMishra, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6473442/1768303) explains how to do exactly what you're asking for, in details. You only need to convert it from C# to VB.NET. Use `ieframe.dll` instead of `shdocvw.dll` to add the reference.

Comment: Hey,

Does anyone have any idea how can i open new window at click on any dynamic link and my problem platform is vb.net and also remember that new window is not internet explorer window or any other browser

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `Navigating` event. Example:

```
webBrowser1.Navigating += Function(source, args) 
    Dim uriClicked = args.Uri
    ' Create your new form or do whatever you want to do here
End Function
```