# how does i open new window at click on any dynamic link in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Does anyone have any idea how can i open new window at click on any dynamic link and my problem platform is vb.net and also remember that new window is not internet explorer window or any other browser give me full source code.

This is what I've tried till now

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    Dim thiselement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim targeturl As String = thiselement.GetAttribute("href") 
    e.Cancel = True
    Dim window As New Form1
    window.Show()
    window.WebBrowser1.Navigate(targeturl)
End Sub
```

Comment: you want to open new browser window 
??

Comment: is there any error with the code you have posted
??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open dynamic WebBrowser link address in new window form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108562/how-to-open-dynamic-webbrowser-link-address-in-new-window-form)

Comment: Duplicate of your own question. You only need to ask once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Download the WebBrowserEx service and install in debug and run folder in bin folder in your project. then use this service browser in your project.

Answer (score 0):

you may also try javascript to open window

```
   Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow

    Dim thiselement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim targeturl As String = thiselement.GetAttribute("href") 
         Response.Write("<script>window.open('"+targeturl+"','_ new', 'width=400,height=200');</script>")
   End Sub
```

Comment: thanks........... but my code on button clicked then open new link can you help me  and i have get null pointer error at "href" means there is no active element error can u please help me can u meet me facebook i have show u my error image and chat

Comment: have you provided attribute value for  href ??

Comment: Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
        Dim thiselement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
        Dim targeturl As String = thiselement.GetAttribute("href")
        e.Cancel = True

        Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + targeturl + "','_ new', 'width=400,height=200');</script>") End Sub......>>>> i got error near syntax "href" like object reference is not set to an instance of an object...so wt can i do for that ???

Comment: this error shows that the attribute your are trying to get is empty. i guess you havn't have provided href value

Comment: if you know where you want to redirect then dont use `thiselement` and `targetelement`. simply use `Response.Write("<script>window.open('/path_of_page_to_Open','_ new', 'width=400,height=200');</script>")`

Comment: I use your code in my form but generated dynamic link will open to Microsoft Internet Expoler.. I want to open that link in my window form. for that i have also set properties e.Cancel=True. so what can i do for that ??......Thanks for reply....

Comment: how i add webbrowserex control in toolbox in vb.net 2010