# vb.net how to catch new window from dynamic webbrowser?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a tabbed browser and put a webbrowser behind the form, so it won't showup in the design or code and cannot call: `Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow`

This is how i load the form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try

        Dim tab As New TabPage
        Dim brws As New WebBrowser
        brws.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        brws.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        tab.Text = " New Tab"
        tab.Controls.Add(brws)
        Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
        Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab
        brws.Navigate("")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

How can i catch the new window from my tabbed browser? I need it to load outgoing/external links to open in new windows and not in IE.

I have tried this but that will do nothing:

```
Private Sub WebBrowserNewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MsgBox("catched the new window")
    End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display a popup from a WebBrowser in another window I created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470842/how-do-i-display-a-popup-from-a-webbrowser-in-another-window-i-created)

Comment: no it is not, that is for c#

Comment: Not meant for you, just the dozens of future googlers that do know how to read C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the line (after creating the control):

`AddHandler brws.NewWindow, AddressOf WebBrowserNewWindow`

for it to handle that event, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.newwindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i used this: `AddHandler brws.NewWindow, AddressOf WebBrowser_NewWindow` and this: `Private Sub WebBrowser_NewWindow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)` it is working :)