# How to achieve isolated session or multiple login support in embedded browser

Tags: c#, c++, browser, webkit

I'm working on an application that requires multiple embedded instances and each of this instance logins to the same external site with different authentication details.

Initially I went with C#.Net but soon realized that webbrowser control shares cookies and there's no way to bypass this. I've read about INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION but it ends session process wide (I need different sessions within the same process ) and is therefore of not much help.

The other alternatives available are embedded webkit (QT4) and firefox. Does anybody have any experience of working with these in a similar use case? Webkit docs do mention a separate QCookieJar - would that mean isolated sessions ?

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Before looking for such a tool, won't you think again about your problem ? This seems rather unconventional to me to simultaneously login with several different credentials. The problem may be solved with a different architecture. Can you develop on what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'll elaborate a bit using GMail as an example site - I need 4 ui panels in 1 window and in each panel, I need to open the gmail page as a different user. IE has a nomerge option for the same purpose. These cannot be separate process as that'll be against the client requirements.

Comment: no comment/answer ?? is my description poor or the solution impossible ?

Comment: I have read your question again and I find it understandable and pertinent (I deleted my previous comment stating that it was not clear). I think nobody answer because your problem is difficult and not very common (no answers on google too). I think the ideas you give at the end are good. Experiment with them, then answer your own question so other people will benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieved using WebKit. I tried PyQt4.QtWebkit but should work for gtk webkit as well.

Comment: I'm facing same problem and no help on internet. Can you show a sample? Did you use WebKit.NET? Thanks

Comment: No. I used PyQt4.QtWebkit. Don't have a sample but its fairly easy, you just need to replace the default cookiejar for the webview with a custom implementation. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do this, but looking for "c# .net web browser session" in google, I found thoses links that lead me to believe it's possible :

- [webBrowser popup window loses session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941848/webbrowser-popup-window-loses-session)
- http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/234116-webbrowser-control-loses-session-state

Most people are trying to get the oposite of what you want, meaning that they are in the state you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue described in the 2 links isn't the same. They are facing the problem of "losing the session". What I need is unshared sessions within the same process I'm not sure if the 2 issues are related. However, I'll be trying webkit soon and post the answer if it works.